# How to use linked objects with an Array modifier?

Tags: modeling

I need to create a bricks wall with linkeds option, for use less memory. But i want use this with a Array modifier(a procedural method) . How do this?

Addendum:

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, if you create a brick wall and want to save memory, you can either use Array (but you can't apply it otherwise it won't save memory anymore), or duplicate your brick with alt D

Comment: I need a procedural method that use duplicate linked objects.

Comment: If by procedural method you mean non-destructive, Array is not destructive, but 1) it tends to be repetitive except with some tricks like displacement, and 2) as soon as you apply the modifier the bricks are not linked any more, but what about bricks that you link-duplicate? With 3 different bricks you can build a whole wall and it will stay very light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method would be to use linked-duplicated bricks (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>).

If you use an *Array* modifier, it has the advantage of being non-destructive and light as long as you don't apply the modifier, but it will give a bit repetitive result. But you can use a *Displacement* modifier to solve the problem:

- Create a 2 brick object, subdivide them a bit.

[image]

- Give it an *Array* modifier on the X axis. Then a second on the Z axis.

[image]
[image]

- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* and smooth it. Then give it a *Displace* modifier with a *Cloud* texture, it will allow you to break the wall uniformity.

[image]

For the brick you show, you can do it this way:

- Create a plane, subdivide it, bevel the new edges.

[image]
[image]

- Drag the central edge to create the slots, give your object a *Subdivision Surface* to check the shape, give it an *Array* on X and Z axis. Put the *Subdivision Surface* modifier below the *Array* modifiers.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: how to add the line in the texture like this:
https://alafantini.it/administrator/public/8_3prodottibase_g.jpg

Comment: you can model it for real or fake it with a bump map, it depends on your needs, if you need to make some close-up shots it would be better to model the grooves

Comment: also do you need to see the inner structure?

Comment: for trasversal architectonic section. Then i need to see empty space inside. 
For line outside brick maybe only bump greek texture

Comment: if you want to model your brick it's rather easy, you need to draw its profile with vertices, then extrude. As it's an industrial type of brick, you don't need to use any noise or displacement in the array.

Comment: I do this, from svg to mesh extrude. But im using the bevel modifier, dont change nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110010/discussion-between-moonboots-and-rerere-l).